# How to use HTML anchors as a table of contents in email when rendered in clients like Groupwise or Gmail?

Tags: html, email

I would like to put a table of contents at the top of an internal **email** newsletter that will allow readers to 'jump' down to the part of the newsletter that interests them.  Something like:

```
<ul>
      <li><a href="#FUNDING">Funding Opportunities</a></li>
      <li><a href="#DEVELOPMENT">Professional Development</a></li>
      <li><a href="#BEST">Best Practices</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then 'further down' in the email newsletter have:

```
<h2><a id="FUNDING">Funding</a></h2>
<!--- news items about funding -->

<h2><a id="DEVELOPMENT">Professional Development</a></h2>
<!--- news items about professional development -->

<h2><a id="BEST">Best Practices</a></h2>
<!--- news items about Best Practices -->
```

**This works fine in browser based HTML**, but I have not had success getting it to work in various email clients (**gmail, groupwise, outlook**).  I have however, received emails that appear to use a technique like above and I am able to 'scroll' the email.  I understand that support in various clients will vary and that this is not necessarily a 'good' practice but this is an internal system and almost all recipients will be using GroupWise.

Any experienced insight into the specific additional markup that is needed **(e.g. what would the base ref be?**) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the 'name' attribute to the anchor as well as the 'id'.

```
<a id="FUNDING" name="FUNDING">
```

Comment: This is not the issue; I did go ahead and put both in, but that does not fix the 'email client' scenario.  As far as w3c and anchor tags using id: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3

Comment: Using @id is indeed best practice, but if you're writing HTML for emails, code like you would've done in the early nineties. See http://www.email-standards.org/ for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I found this post when trying to accomplish the same thing, and I followed instructions here to get it to work: http://blog.mailermailer.com/tips-resources/anchor-tags-html-emails

This is the code I ended up with in the first successful test:

```
<html>
<a name="BACKTOTOP">Index</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#COMPLIANCE">Compliance Courses</a></li>
<li><a href="#DEALERTRAINING">Dealer Training</a></li>
<li><a href="#FUNCTIONALAREA">Functional Training Courses</a></li>
<br>
<h1>
<a name="COMPLIANCE">Compliance</a>
</h1>
<br>
This will be the message for Compliance courses.
<br>
<a href="#BACKTOTOP">Return to top index</a>
<br>
<h1>
<a name="DEALERTRAINING">Dealer Training</a>
</h1>
<br>
This will be the message for Dealer Training.
<br>
<a href="#BACKTOTOP">Return to top index</a>
<br>
<h1>
<a name="FUNCTIONALAREA">Functional Training Courses</a>
</h1>
<br>
This will be the message for courses by Functional Area.
<br>
<a href="#BACKTOTOP">Return to top index</a>
</html>
```