# a href link doesn't work in gmail

Tags: html, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use HTML anchors as a table of contents in email when rendered in clients like Groupwise or Gmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045460/how-to-use-html-anchors-as-a-table-of-contents-in-email-when-rendered-in-clients)

I have used the following code:

```
<a href="#section">Section</a>
```

It doesnt seem to work in gmail. Any suggestion?

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: If the link points to external resource it should contain full absolute URL. If you are linking to the part of this email - I do not think email clients and services will be happy to support it.

Comment: Most email clients remove ALOT of attributes. Maybe Gmail strips it?